# Using script tag in Angular 6 component.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm aware that Angular removes the script tags in the `component.html` files, but from all the different forums I've checked out, I haven't found one to successfully solve my problem.
I'm trying to put this code into my `ontology.component.html` file

```
<script>
  var widget_tree = $("#widget_tree").NCBOTree({
     apikey: "<my-api-key>",
     ontology: "ENVO"
  });
</script>
```

My `index.html` already has the necessary scripts as well

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/widgets/jquery.ncbo.tree.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../src/widgets/jquery.ncbo.tree-2.0.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You will very likely experience issues trying to use Angular with jQuery. It is recommended you find angular compatible modules so that you can ensure they can hook into the Angular component lifecycle and rendering.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using angular6 then you can place it inside the script[] section of `angular.json` file or for angular 4/5 filename is `.angular-cli`

```
"scripts": [
    "path/to/scripts/file1.js",
    "path/to/scripts/file2.js"
]
```

---

Your below coce might not be working because at that time, `"#widget_tree"` node is not been created in DOM, just try to add these code in some `setTimeout()`

```
<script>
  var widget_tree = $("#widget_tree").NCBOTree({
     apikey: "<my-api-key>",
     ontology: "ENVO"
  });
</script>
```

like

```
    <script>
    function injectAPIKey() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          var widget_tree = $("#widget_tree").NCBOTree({
             apikey: "<my-api-key>",
             ontology: "ENVO"
          });
        }, 10000);
    }

injectAPIKey();

</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly why you should avoid using jQuery with dynamically rendered Angular components. jQuery has no way of knowing when Angular components have finished rendering and if the elements/components re-render event handlers or similar will be lost.